# Extracting substring using Scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

Trying to extract information from Wikipedia pages. Originally I wanted to identify which pages were about companies. I used the following regex to check if the word company was between the phrase "infobox" and the first "|" character,

```
val text = (...wikipedia page xml...)
val infobox_company = """\{\{.*(?i)infobox[^\|]*company[^\|]*\|""".r
val is_company = infobox_company findFirstIn text != None
```

Now I'd like to count all of the different types of infoboxes that are present in Wikipedia. I tried altering my regex expression and tested it on a sample:

```
val infobox_regex = """\{\{.*(?i)infobox[^\|](.*)[^\|]*\|""".r
val test_str = "{{Infobox dot-com company | name = 'my_doc_com'}}"
val infobox_regex(info_type) = test_str
```

The regex pattern doesn't match, so I get a scala.MatchError.

How should I alter my regex expression to extract the infobox type (i.e. the substring between "infobox" and the first instance of "|")?

Comment: capture the group(group 1 precisely) check this out https://regex101.com/r/kU4tF7/1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment, the solution is

```
val infobox_regex = """\{\{.*(?i)infobox(.*)[^\|]*\|""".r
val info_box_list = (for(m <- infobox_regex findAllMatchIn test_str) yield m group 1).toList
```